# How to create sequential numbers in a field by defining automatically the start, end and interval numbers?

Tags: arcpy, python, field-calculator, expression, autoincrement

I would like to create sequential numbers in a field called "virtual _Li".

[image]

I have used the field calculator using `def autoincrement()` function and manually calculate the interval number. 
https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011137

[image]

But I would like to have it in python.

The start point should be always the number in `“Z_2018”` that has `“0”` in `“First_Dist”` (Start = 1.006).
End number is the number in `“Z_2018”` that has the Maximum number in `“FIRST_DIST”` (End = 1.04).

The interval is:`( (End) – (Start) ) / ( max in “FIRST_DIST” field/a constant number )`

Constant number is always = 0.15

Start and end number can be `+` or `–` number.

In this case interval is `0.002875793`

```
( (1.040) –  (1.006) ) / (1.773424/0.15) = 0.002875793
```

First create a field:

```
arcpy.AddField_management(ProfileGraph1WR1, "Virtual_Li", "DOUBLE", 10, 3)
```

then I need to create a “codeblock” and “Expression” which I don’t know How.

Comment: To confirm, this is working within the ArcMap window but you are just looking to convert it to arcpy?

Comment: Yes! it works with field calculator in ArcMap and manually calculating the Interval. but I want it automatically with arcpy.

Comment: I think I'm still missing how you are making the choice for increment value, but the answer below has the base code for making the codeblock/expression for use in arcpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code Example 3 on [Esri's documentation for Calculate Field](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field.htm) is probably the closest to your question.

Since you have up through the AddField, the code below proceeds from there based on that example.

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("ProfileGraph1WR1", ["First_Dist", "Z_2018"]) as cursor:
    firstdistvals = dict()       
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == 0: 
            startval = row[1]
        firstdistvals[row[0]] = row[1]
    maxval = max(firstdistvals.keys())
    endval = firstdistvals[maxval]


# Set local variables
inTable = "ProfileGraph1WR1"
fieldName = ""Virtual_Li"
expression = "autoIncrement({}, {}, {})".format(startval, endval, maxval)  

codeblock = """
    rec = 0
    def autoIncrement(start, end, maximum):  
        global rec
        const = 0.15
        pStart = float(start)
        pInterval = (float(end) – float(start))  / (float(maximum)/const)
        if (rec == 0):
            rec = pStart
        else:
            rec += pInterval
        return rec"""

# Execute CalculateField 
arcpy.CalculateField_management(inTable, fieldName, expression, "PYTHON_9.3", codeblock)
```

Comment: How the code calculate the interval? I want it automatically calculated.

Comment: I'll add in SearchCursor based checks to determine start/end.

Comment: Updated answer posted; please test

Comment: I got error:ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of VB | PYTHON | PYTHON_9.3.
ERROR 000989: Python syntax error: Parsing error IndentationError: unexpected indent (line 2)
Failed to execute (CalculateField).

Comment: I copied from Pro documentation instead of 10.x. Updated to use "PYTHON_9.3"

Comment: I changed it but I  got again the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84872/discussion-between-smiller-and-anahita-kp).

Comment: it works, my python gives error because of the spaces in PInterval. now it works :pInterval = (float(end)-float(start))/(float(maximum)/const). Thanks!